# ASP.net MVC - Call other controller from view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

try to call from view in "Transaction" controller, The other "CreditCard" controller:

```
@(Url.Action("ShowImage", "CreditCard"))/" + ConcatString
```

from src propery of IMG tag.
but because it from other controller the URL is invalid.
Insted Of:

```
/creditcard/showimage/45809014157220320
```

Its:

```
/Transaction/TransactionToPDF/creditcard/showimage/45809014157220320
```

Comment: Did you forget a leading slash?

Comment: Didnt understand why this rendered: "/Transaction/TransactionToPDF/"

Comment: May you show all codes on Url.Action line?

Comment: <img src="@(Url.Action("ShowImage", "CreditCard"))/" + ConcatString)" class="img float-xs-right" width="350" height="380" id="creditCardImage" />

Comment: Try putting a `/` before your `@Url.Action`

Comment: Can you add routeconfig codes to post if its possible?

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess, your Action doesn't accept a `null` for the image id? Rather than trying to add `concatstring` try specifying the parameter e.g.,

```
@Url.Action("ShowImage", "CreditCard", new { ImageId= ConcatString })
```

Again, depending on what the allowed parameters are for the Action this should let the correct URL be resolved by the routing system

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use Html.Action helper. But it is easier for me to do it like this.

```
   <img src="/CreditCard/ShowImage/@ConcatString" class="img float-xs-right" width="350" height="380" id="creditCardImage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an "Area" issue.  If they are in different areas, you should be able to do this:

```
@(Url.Action("ShowImage", "CreditCard", new { area = "" }))/" + ConcatString
```